# Render block in twig file drupal 8

Tags: blocks

I have created a block in custom block library, i need to render the block on all pages except home page.

Unfortunately I need to do it in twig file only because of ui issues if I enabled in the block layout UI

In twig file how can I render the block in drupal 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in "themename.theme"

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('block_id');
  $block_content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('block')
    ->view($block);
 $variables['your_block_name'] = $block_content;
}
```

in twig template file use following variable

```
{{ your_block_name }}
```

Comment: Note that this will make the variable your_block_name available in the page.html.twig . For other template files use the appropriate preprocess hook. E.g. theme_preprocess_node for node.html.twig files